# Mouse and Cat chasing game

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to make a Windows Form Application which has to be a cat chasing a mouse. And you move the mouse with the arrow keys while that cat is going towards the mouse. It should detect when they both get in contact and show the time it took.

Both the cat and mouse should be placed randomly in the window each new game. And in higher difficulty, it should have two holes and when the mouse goes in one of them it shows on the other. Can someone help because I have no idea where to start the main part?

I've already placed pictures if a cat and a mouse in separate picture boxes and made the part with choosing difficulty.

Comment: Start by displaying the cat and mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You'd basically be combining these steps:

- Implement an OnKeyDown handler to respond to key presses. Reposition the mouse image when this occurs.
- Create a timer for the cat animation. At each step move the cat towards the mouse's position.
- Whenever the position of one of the objects changes, check if there's a collision and handle it appropriately.

It's pretty simple to do this with a game engine as well. That would handle the animation for you. Here's how you'd get started with Unity for example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn759441.aspx

Comment: The problem is it is a school project and I HAVE to use Windows Form Application. I pretty sure I can do it in unity but it won't do it in this case. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I am not sure you can do it in Unity either.